# Delphi 10.4 Run (Debug Mode) Not Showing Application

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4-sydney, debug-mode

I'm trying to run my application in debug mode, but the IDE isn't showing it on the screen. When I try to close the project or the IDE, it gives me this message:

"This current debug session must end before the requested operation can complete. Please indicate how you would like to end the debug session.
<kbd>Terminate</kbd>   <kbd>Detach</kbd>   <kbd>Cancel</kbd>   <kbd>Help</kbd> "

[image: message1]

And when I choose either terminate or detach, it gives me another message:

"Debugger fatal error during process reset: 'Debug process is already running'. Please save your work and restart Delphi 10.4."

[image: message2]

The application opens up fine when I run without debugging, though. I haven't changed anything in my environment, so I'm not really sure where to begin looking.

I checked the Task Manager if other processes had the application open, and it was only open under "Embarcadero RAD Studio for Windows". I've tried restarting my computer, but it made no difference.

Comment: Are we talking here about 32 bit or 64 bit application? When debugging 32 bit application Delphi connects its debugger to ti directly. But when debugging 64 bit application debugging is done with the help of PAServer with which Delphi communicates using network connection. So if this netowkr connection is being blocked by your FireWall or your AntiVirus software Delphi might not be able to properly debug 64 bit application or potentially even force stop of such application since it can't send required command to the attacked debugger though PAServer.

Comment: Another thing that you might want to check is your main form Lent and Top position values at design-time. It is possible that your application is simply show outside of your monitor viewing area. Can happen quite quickly if at some point you have been using multi-monitor setup but are currently on a single-monitor setup.

Comment: Please add the dialog texts as, well, text not as an image. Those dialogs texts can simply be copied to the clipboard with Ctrl + C.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Comment: Have you tried a new application straight out of the box?

Comment: @SilverWarior, your first comment was very helpful and was exactly what I needed to check. I also found this [link](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6489-can-someone-provide-inbound-and-outbound-ports-used-by-ide/) helpful.

Comment: @ramson48, did you find a solution to this? I face the exact same problem, but it remains after opening up the firewall, and also giving "Debug programs" rights to my user (not sure if it matters here). It would be useful to hear exactly what you did to make it work. It if was clear, maybe you could even answer your own question here?